# Can IntelliJ IDEA auto-import Play dependencies?

Tags: playframework, intellij-idea, playframework-2.0

I'm can't figure out how to get IntelliJ IDEA to "play nice" with Play. I'm wondering how/if you can get it to automatically recognize dependencies in Build.scala and import them, just like IDEA can do with pom.xml entries for Maven projects.

As it is now, I have to manually keep my IDEA project and Build.scala in sync, which is kind of a pain.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

IntelliJ is working on sbt support (like they have for Maven).  Until then just re-run `play idea` when you change your dependencies.

Comment: If you want to try out the sbt plugin, check out: http://blog.jetbrains.com/scala/2013/07/17/sbt-plugin-nightly-builds/

Comment: Sweet. That's the missing piece of the puzzle. I guess I just assumed that because IDEA has *Play* support it would have all the related build stuff already. Now I know I can stop searching for a feature that isn't even there :)

Comment: In my case re-running "play idea" doubles the dependencies which have already been there. Not a big deal, but very annoying.

Comment: @cosmolev I noticed that in the module config.  Most of the time it doesn't screw anything up.  But sometimes I have to delete the `.idea*` directories and re-run `play idea`.

Comment: You can also get the sources with: idea with-sources=yes.